# Ionic Firebase Google Login Error 10 in Capacitor Project

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, google-signin, capacitor

I know that this famous problem was covered by several forums and topics, and believe me I tried their solutions, but the famous error 10 from the Google Login is still there.
I will explain it the clearest way I can.

1. This is an Ionic project integrated with Capacitor using the "cordova-plugin-googleplus" plugin. I installed both cordova and ionic/native packages
2. I went to Google Cloud Platform and set the Web Client ID and Secret Key for Firebase Authentication
3. I have generate a keystore (the androiddebugkey example)
4. Then, I built the apk key from Android Studio (I also tried to generate it from the terminal) with V1 and V2 signatures, for debug and release apks and after that I signed them by terminal
5. After, I registered the SHA1 key in Firebase Project
6. I took the code example of the plugin documentation for the project and then tried to login in my device.

Ok, I get the google login screen but after that the error 10 comes along.

Solutions with no results:

- I created a debug-signing.properties with the keystore and key info. I wrote the path to the debug-signing.properties in the gradle.properties. The three in the android folder.

```
keyAlias=androiddebugkey 
keyPassword=android 
storeFile=<PATH-TO-KEYSTORE> 
storePassword=android
```

- I added the cordova plugin variables in config.xml

  ```
   <variable name="WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID" value="XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
  </plugin>
  ```
- I tried  the google.login() function with different parameters

```
     if (this.platform.is('capacitor'))
          {
            const googleAuth = await this.google.login({});
            console.log(googleAuth);
            const googleCredential = googleAuth.accessToken ?
              firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential
                (
                  googleAuth.idToken,
                  googleAuth.accessToken
                ) :
              firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleAuth.idToken);
            console.log(googleCredential);
            credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
          }
```

```
 if (this.platform.is('capacitor'))
          {
            const googleAuth = await this.google.login({ 'webClientId': environment.webGoogleId,
 'offline': true, 'scope': 'profile email' });
            console.log(googleAuth);
            const googleCredential = googleAuth.accessToken ?
              firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential
                (
                  googleAuth.idToken,
                  googleAuth.accessToken
                ) :
              firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleAuth.idToken);
            console.log(googleCredential);
            credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
          }
```

- I checked the issue with android-client-id and web-client-id from google cloud OAuth to use web-client-id in the app, not android, with no results.

So finally I got no solutions

gradle.properties :

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=debug-signing.properties
cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=release-signing.properties
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.company.comanda" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Comandera</name>
    <description>Aplicacion para restaurantes</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Los movimentarios</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <icon background="resources/android/icon/ldpi-background.png" density="ldpi" foreground="resources/android/icon/ldpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon background="resources/android/icon/mdpi-background.png" density="mdpi" foreground="resources/android/icon/mdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon background="resources/android/icon/hdpi-background.png" density="hdpi" foreground="resources/android/icon/hdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon background="resources/android/icon/xhdpi-background.png" density="xhdpi" foreground="resources/android/icon/xhdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon background="resources/android/icon/xxhdpi-background.png" density="xxhdpi" foreground="resources/android/icon/xxhdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon background="resources/android/icon/xxxhdpi-background.png" density="xxxhdpi" foreground="resources/android/icon/xxxhdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm">
        <variable name="WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID" value="XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    </plugin>
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100" sessionid="15afd298" />
</widget>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.comanda"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.warn("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

Please if you can guide me somehow I will be very thankful.

Comment: do you fixed this issue?

Comment: Sorry , Yes i did it, pls for god sake check the Google Cloud Platform and the API key that u use, and make the SHAX thing very carrefully.

Comment: @AlejandroPlanes Hey can you link me a artcile related setup this SHAX?